# How to insert return value from templatetag to {% if

Tags: django, django-templates

I have templatetag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_something(data, var1, var2):
    if data:
        if var1:
            if var2:
                return True
return False
```

And ho to insert this to {% if ... %} block? This is not working:

```
{% if get_something 1 1 0 %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Have your tag [set a variable in the context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#setting-a-variable-in-the-context), and use that variable instead.